# How to optimise SQL table for read speed for point to point distance data

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, database-design, azure-sql-database

I intend to store a list of distances from all points to each other.

So if I had only 3 points (A-C) it would be like

```
 | FROM | TO | DISTANCE
 | A    | B  | 10 miles
 | A    | C  | 15 miles
 | B    | C  | 12 miles
```

Obviously you can infer that B to A = 10 miles since you know A to B = 10 miles. In terms of my queries I may be searching for A to B or B to A - I can't guarantee the order of the start and end point of the journey.

I have 1600 points which makes (1600^2 - 1600)/2 = 1.3m possible journeys. What is the best way to store that data for querying by either A to B or B to A?

- Should I duplicate the rows for the reverse journeys leading to 2.5m
  rows and query on that?
- Or should I make a composite clustered index
  on the two columns and search for both the A to B OR the B to A
  knowing at least one exists?
- Or something else clever

This is a common enough problem surely and so I want to know from a DB expert if there is a **common pattern or practice** for solving it. **I want facts, references, or specific expertise to answer this question** not just vague opinions as I have plenty of them myself :)

This is on SQL Azure in case that makes a difference

Comment: Are you using Geospatial or are the points more conceptual/contextual and you happen to know the distance between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i were to solve this, rather than saying From and To column, I would call it Point1 and Point2 and always make sure that point2 is greater than point1, in your case C>B , B>A and C>A

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if Column Values contain names of points instead of A,B,C?

Comment: B>A means , point2 alphabetically comes later that point1 as in , newyork>newdelhi